# Trouble databinding in code to wpf listbox from custom IList implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a class CustomCollection : IList which maintains a list of CustomObject Types.

This is what I tried, but it's not working (provider.Data is readonly):

```
CustomCollection collection1 = somesampledata;

ObjectDataProvider provider = new ObjectDataProvider();
provider.ObjectType = typeof(CustomObject);
provider.Data = collection1;
// could provider.Method = "collection1.GetItems", or something similar work?

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = provider;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneTime;

listBox1.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `provider.Data`, try `provider.ObjectInstance = collection1`.

Comment: Thanks! provider.ObjectInstance = collection1.GetItems() works! (But you have to remove the line provider.ObjectType = or you get an exception - you can only assign one of those properties )